# Удалить GET Params в URL

Tags: javascript

Так получаю `GET params` после того как все флажки сняты с `checkbox`
`$(".checkbox_campaigns_id")` так добавляю параметры к определенным ссылкам.

```
$(".checkbox_campaigns_id").attr("href", function(i, origValue){
    console.log(origValue);
        return origValue;
});
```

Ответ

```
/ru/statistics/ads?id=11&act_id=act_627387174454648&adset_id=23843999445570740&campaigns_id=23843999454240740,23843999445580740&campaigns_id=23843999445580740
```

Подскажите как можно удалить `&adset_id=23843999445570740&campaigns_id=23843999454240740,23843999445580740&campaigns_id=23843999445580740`

что бы получилось `/ru/statistics/ads?id=11&act_id=act_627387174454648`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если одинаковый порядок параметров не гарантирован, то лучше парсить всю строку:

```js
var str = '/ru/statistics/ads?id=11&act_id=act_627387174454648&adset_id=23843999445570740&campaigns_id=23843999454240740,23843999445580740&campaigns_id=23843999445580740';
var base = str.split('?')[0];
var getParams = str.split('?')[1];
var filteredParams = getParams.split('&').filter(key => /^(id)|(act_id)=/.test(key)).join('&');
var filteredUrl = base + '?' + filteredParams;
console.log(filteredUrl);
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Answer (score 2):

Если не хочется заниматься веселой пляски с регулярками, и порядок чем-то (чем?) гарантирован то можно брутфорсить:

```
const str ='/ru/statistics/ads?id=11&act_id=act_627387174454648&adset_id=23843999445570740&campaigns_id=23843999454240740,23843999445580740&campaigns_id=23843999445580740';

const splitter = (str) =>{
  const [first, second] = str.split('&');
  return [first,second].join('&')
} // ru/statistics/ads?id=11&act_id=act_627387174454648
```